# name for set of v such that (v,Mv)=0

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

Given an indefinite symmetric matrix $M$, is there a name for the set of vectors mapped to 0 by the quadratic form, $(v,Mv)=0$. This includes the nullspace of $M$ by also all the vectors for which the positive definite and negative definite parts of M cancel out.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community I'm looking for the name of a set, if a conventional one exists. Something analogous to "nullspace" but for a quadratic form. I don't see how there's any ambiguity in my question.

Comment: [isotropic vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotropic_quadratic_form)

Comment: @nejimban I don't have enough credit to vote up a comment but if you put this as an answer I can accept it--this is all I was looking for

Comment: @sayda no worries, we can just leave it there